# Find distance between two customers using address

Tags: magento2, google-cloud

I have to find the distance between two customers using their address. I tried getting latitude and longitude of the customers using google map geocode API. But I encounter this error **"You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at [https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable"](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable%22)**.
Is there any way I can get latitude longitude without having to create a billing account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way around this with Google Cloud Console, you will get $200 free usage each month. How many requests are you planning on making a month?
Do you need the latitude and longitude to calculate the distance?

Comment: Yes i need to find distance

Comment: You can do offline calculations using geo_names